# Robust estimation of mean with small sample size

Tags: mean, robust, small-sample

Working with a 2D sensor.  A row consists of 4096 samples, of which there are 16 *reference* samples (the rest are *active*).  The reference samples do not measure the signal, but are used to estimate the unique measurement offset that affects the entire row. The measurements must be corrected by this row offset before being further processed.  This row offset varies between successive rows, and also over time. Each sample is independently affected by measurement noise which seems to follow a Gaussian distribution.

So a given measurement $M$ is given by the signal at that location $S$ plus the row offset $O$ plus some Gaussian noise $G$, thus:

$$M_{xy} = S_{xy} + O_{y} + G_{xy}$$

The typical procedure is to use the mean of these reference measurements to estimate this offset and subtract it from the active measurements (the remaining samples in that row) to obtain a corrected measurement:

$$O_{y} = \Sigma M_{ref}/N$$ when $N=16, S=0$ (in the reference samples).

Of course, when $S=0$, $M=O_{y} + G_{xy}$ so we still need to filter out the noise to get the offset.

Currently, using the mean we can get the noise (stddev) quite low, but there is still sufficient noise that there are noticeable artefacts in the results.  So we are looking for a more robust way (than mean or median) of estimating the offset from these samples.

If it helps, during the calibration procedure, we are able to obtain "zero" level readings from the entire row. Thus under lab conditions (and *not* in the field), we can read out the zero level from the entire row.

So the question is:

- How can you robustly estimate the mean value of a small ($N=16$) noisy set of samples that are representative of a much larger population?

and the bonus question:

- Is there a way to exploit the "zero" measurements available only during calibration?

This answer seems closest to this question, but so far the methods described don't seem to yield a significant improvement:

- [Crash course in robust mean estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24054/crash-course-in-robust-mean-estimation)

Comment: Thinking more about this, it seems there should be some useful way to exploit the 'zero' measurements during calibration to more accurately model the black reference measurements and get a better estimate? We know they are from the same population.